# How to remove beforeunload handler after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I have script which will run if anyone try to refresh page, but after my ajax success response I want this script should not work or get removed. How to do this?

Script which need to be removed

```js
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  return $(".clk_mdl2").click();
});
```

This is ajax which will get all data after this above mentioned script should be removed automatically.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "<?= base_url('Users/get_data') ?>",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    id: id
  },
  success: function(data) {
    if (data === ok) {
      //remove above  onbeforeunload script 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable "window.onbeforeunload" when submit form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838894/how-to-disable-window-onbeforeunload-when-submit-form)

Comment: @Ashraf there are no jQuery off example in that link

Comment: @mplungjan `window.onbeforeunload` is the native method , it works also :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply unbind this event with [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$(window).off('beforeunload')
```